# SelectionInput Checkbox change value programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I have a list of items with checkbox and there is one checkbox at the end labelled "Select All". I would like to check all the items when the user checks the "Select All" checkbox, or maybe even clicking a button. Is there a way to do this or this is not possible?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: I might be wrong, but AFAIK we can't update widgets/sections as of now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not possible unfortunately.  All the code you write is run server side, therefore there is no client side code to update your UI.  The only way to change content on a card is to replace the card with a new card.  You could simulate this action by returning a sort of cloned card with the change that you want to happen, but because it will return from the server, it won’t be as seamless as you would like.  I hope that helps.